# How to represent a breadcrumb child?

Tags: javascript, html, breadcrumbs, sightly

I represent the breadcrumb in a table as follow:

```
    <ol class="breadcrumb" data-sly-use.breadcrumb="myModel.js">
    <output data-sly-unwrap data-sly-list="${breadcrumb}">
        <li  itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
            <a href="${item.href}" itemprop="url">
                <span  itemprop="title">${item.label}</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </output>
</ol>
```

How to represent the `breadcrumb child` in this structure?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using apache sling, which I haven't used myself, but for setting up a simple breadcrumb, it can be done just with CSS. Here is one which I set up using `display: inline` on the the li.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StevenIseki/daqfj5ym/)

I'm sure you could use some pretty nice styling on it, but this is a simple example using a triangle for the arrows on the breadcrumb.

#### html

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" itemprop="url">
        <span itemprop="title">item 1</span>
      </a>
    </li>

    <div class="arrow-right"></div>

    <li>
      <a href="#" itemprop="url">
        <span itemprop="title">item 2</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

#### css

```
.arrow-right {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 0.5em solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0.5em solid transparent; 
    border-left: 0.5em solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}

#menu ul{
  list-style: none;
}

#menu li{
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: apologies this was just a solution using CSS, rather than an example using Sling. I would imagine each <li> item would be the child property of the <ol> ordered list, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your question is. What do you mean by "breadcrumb child"? In the Sightly example you give each `item` is one of the elements of the breadcrumb, so that is what I would assume the "child" is, but that doesn't seem to be what you mean.

If the question is about what `myModel.js` might look like, it would simply have to implement the [javascript Use API](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/sightly/use-api-in-javascript.html) and return a list of objects. For example

```
"use strict";
use(function () {
    var crumbs= [];

    crumbs.push({href: '/home/path', label: 'Home'});
    crumbs.push({href: '/section/path', label: 'Section'});

    return crumbs;
});
```

Rather than hard coding the crumbs you can use the objects that Sling gives you to get the parents of the current page, but this works as a simple example.

**note:** At this point you should probably use the Java API, rather than the javascript API for production code. See the comparison chart from Adobe's [Sightly Intro](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/sightly.html)